# how can I run a piece of jQuery/ajax when a certain php variable = 1?

Tags: php, ajax, variables

Good evening guys,

how can I run a piece of jQuery/ajax when a certain php variable = 1 ? *Example* script:

```
if $add_total > < $available_achievement_1 { $achievement_1 = '1' }

       if $achievement_1 == '1' {

    query submit achievement to users database

    }
    else {}
```

So when $achievement_1 = 1 it runs a query, after that it should run the following jQuery/ajax

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {   
            var notice = '<div class="notice">'
                + '<div class="notice-body">' 
                + '<img src="core/displays/notify/achievement-icon.png" alt="" />'
                + '<h3>Achievement item</h3>'
                + '<p>details.</p>'
                + '</div>'
                + '<div class="notice-bottom">'
                + '</div>'
                + '</div>';

            $ny( notice ).purr(
                {
                    usingTransparentPNG: true
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if $add_total > < $available_achievement_1 { $achievement_1 = '1' }

if $achievement_1 == '1' {

    query submit achievement to users database

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {   
                var notice = '<div class="notice">'
                    + '<div class="notice-body">' 
                    + '<img src="core/displays/notify/achievement-icon.png" alt="" />'
                    + '<h3>Achievement item</h3>'
                    + '<p>details.</p>'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '<div class="notice-bottom">'
                    + '</div>'
                    + '</div>';

                $ny( notice ).purr(
                    {
                        usingTransparentPNG: true
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    <?PHP

}
else {}
```

You can add html inside of php conditionals

Comment: @MaartenHartman, I'm actually only one person, but no problem. Come right back if you need more help!

Comment: I laughed :) Humor on a coding site... who would have thought? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the printing of the whole Javascript block inside the `if` statement (ending the `<?php` via `?>` first and resuming it after the JS/HTML). That way it'll only get sent to the client browser if it should run.